# Stored procedure implementation onto a nested drop down button

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-core

I have a hoverable dropdown menu I made in my css which opens up the dropdown items under the button when the cursor hovers over it. This dropdown button displays a series of category names in which its information is stored in my SQL Server.

I have a stored procedure which returns all the category names and successfully populates the dropdown button with category names from SQL Server. However I want to add onto this dropdown button in which when I click one of the category names another dropdown menu items appear with subcategory names where the user can choose from.

My stored procedure takes in two parameters, a `userId` and a `CategoryId` (right now I only trying to implement `categoryId` part first, will use a constant `userId`). Where I am struggling with is how to implement when a user clicks a category name in the dropdown menu the stored procedure receives the `categoryid` for the clicked category and then runs the stored procedure and displays the correct subcategories next to it.

.cshtml:

```
<div class="my_dropdown">
    <button class="my_dropbtn">
        Categories:::
        <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>

    <div class="my_dropdown-content">

        @foreach (var item in Model.category)
        {
            <div class="dropdown">
                <button class="dropdown">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CategoryName)
                    <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                </button>

                <div class="dropdown-item">
                    @foreach (var subitem in Model.subcategory)
                    {
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => subitem.SubCategoryName)
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    }
                </div>
            </div>             
        }

    </div>
</div>
```

Code behind .cshtml

```
public class CreatePortfolioModel : PageModel
{
    CategoryDAL objCategory = new CategoryDAL();
    public List<CategoryTB> category { get; set; }
    public List<SubCategoryTB> subcategory { get; set; }

    public void OnGet()
    {
        category = objCategory.GetAllCategoires().ToList();
        subcategory = objCategory.GetAllSubCategories(1, 2).ToList();
    }
}
```

Where stored procedures are called

```
public IEnumerable<CategoryTB> GetAllCategoires()
{
        List<CategoryTB> lstcategory = new List<CategoryTB>();

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SelectCategories", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                CategoryTB category = new CategoryTB();

                category.CategoryId = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["CategoryId"]);
                category.CategoryName = rdr["CategoryName"].ToString();


                lstcategory.Add(category);
            }
            con.Close();
        }
        return lstcategory;
}

public IEnumerable<SubCategoryTB> GetAllSubCategories(int userID, int CategoryID)
{
        List<SubCategoryTB> lstsubcategory = new List<SubCategoryTB>();
        string _userID = Convert.ToString(userID);
        //_userID = $" \"{_userID}\", ";
        string _categoryID = Convert.ToString(CategoryID);
        //_categoryID = $" \"{_categoryID}\" ";

        string spName = "sp_GetSubCategory";

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(spName, con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@userId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = userID;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@CategoryId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = CategoryID;

            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                SubCategoryTB subcategory = new SubCategoryTB();

                subcategory.SubCategoryName = rdr["SubCategoryName"].ToString();


                lstsubcategory.Add(subcategory);
            }
            con.Close();
        }
        return lstsubcategory;
}
```

When I run my webapp with the code above with two constant parameters I receive this screenshot:

https://gyazo.com/e636d4dabd8edbdd778397ee7cf3c204

I want the first hover over the button to just display the category names then when the user clicks a category name the subcategories are displayed beside the dropdown. Not all at once as shown in the screenshot. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/creating-simple-cascading-dropdownlist-in-asp-net-core-mvc-with-new-tag-helpers/) demo